# How to use superclasses methods when we are working with arraylists?

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, subclass, superclass

I created arraylist of a subclass and didn't get how to use method of superclass. I think i should cast it but couldn't do it.

so i have these superclass and subclass.

```
 public class Course extends Item  {
    private String courseCode;
    DayTime dayTime;
    Lecturer lecturer;
    

    public Course(String name, String code) {
        setCourseName(name);
        setCourseCode(code);
    }
}

public class Item {
    
    private String courseName;

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

}
```

What i try to do is create an arraylist type of Course and use getCourseName to compare with another string. I have an error probably because of myCourse arraylist is type of Course and getCourseName method is in Item superclass.

```
String CourseN=input.nextLine();
for(int i=0;i<myCourse.size();i++) {
    if(( myCourse.getCourseName(i).equals(CourseN));
...
```

Comment: if `myCourse` is a `List` then you must retrieve an element from it to invoke methods on the element, maybe `myCourse.get(i).getCourseName()`.  But it's unclear how inheritance factors in here, or what the exact type of `myCourse` may be, and these matter.

Comment: I think your problem is that you're calling it ``myCourse.getCourseName(i)`` is wrong, there is no getCourseName(int).

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a class you inherit its public methods as in ur case . Now you can directly call these methods on child class objects.

You are getting an error because you are trying to get it from arraylist
if(( myCourse.getCourseName(i).equals(CourseN));
instead you should fetch as if(( myCourse.get(i).getCourseName(i).equals(CourseN));

By myCourse.get(i) , you first fetch the child class object from the list on which you call getCourseName(i).